# Do I need to set a wakelock if a service is put in the foreground in oreo?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Do I need to set a wakelock if a service is put in the foreground in oreo?

Also, connected to the previous one:

The flow is like this, simplified for easier understanding:

MainActivity -> ContextCompat.startForegroundService of MyService-Intent -> in MyService: onStartCommand -> thread start -> in Thread: Thread.sleep

Sometimes, wenn Thread.sleep is longer than a certain time, the execution of the thread stops. Once I activate the phone again, the execution continues. How to constantly continue it?

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because your device enters to doze mode when user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of time, with the screen off refer this more details https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#understand_app_standby, one alternative is to use work manager refer this for more details https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics